# CSS Background color is not full, it does not cover the whole page properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-color

I am trying to add background color to my page, but it does not cover the whole page properly.

Screenshot 1:As it can be seen here, there are white space on the background after the cards:

[image]

CSS CODE

```
#background  
{   
    background-color:#9B59B6;
    margin: -19px 0 0 0; /*-19px here to remove white space on the very top of the page*/
    width: 100%;  
}
```

If I add :

```
position:absolute; 
height:100%; 
width:100%;
```

It would solve the problem, However, it would cause another problem like this:

Screenshot 2:Here, when I added more cards, and scroll it down, there is a white space below the background:

[image]

CSS CODE for screenshot 2

```
#background
{ 
    position:absolute; 
    height:100%; 
    width:100%;
    background-color:#9B59B6;
    margin: -19px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

How do I solve this? I tried using `position:relative` or `overflow:hidden`, But it does not help.

I am doing this on ASP.net MVC 6, so the format is cshtml instead of html.

Please help, Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make use of [viewheight](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_types_length_vh) and viewwidth:

```
html, 
body, 
#background { 
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #9B59B6;
}
```

Perhaps make it static (without the min- prefix) and add zero padding/margin to fix a white gap.

Comment: I was having a problem when the page is smaller the background was not showing to full of it's height but this solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
body{background-color:#9B59B6;}
```

This should work. But what is the html element that #background id is set to?

I guess that is where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Your body is not set to 100% height I think.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

and then

```
#background {
    height: 100%;
}
```

But why not set the background color property directly to the body ?

Answer (score 2):

Color the body

```
 body{
     background-color:black;
  }
```

Comment: I tried, but it is exactly like in screenshot 1, it does not cover the whole page. It only covers up to the last cards. i am doing this on cshtml ASP.net so I can't use the body property.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure cover the whole body property

```css
body  
{   
    background-color:#9B59B6;
    margin: -19px 0 0 0; /*-19px here to remove white space on the very top of the page*/
    width: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<html>
  
  <body >
    </body>
  </html>
```

The problem may happen because you are implementing `id` of a particular div(like `#background`) specifically. make sure to use `body`property.

Comment: Hi JokerFan, I am doing this not on HTML5. I'm doing this on ASP.net, so the format is a little bit different, It uses div instead of body. I will edit the question a bit. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

You should properly use `body { background: #9B59B6 }` or you well need to make your `#background` fixed instead of `absolute`

```
#background
{ 
    position:fixed; 
    height:100%; 
    width:100%;
    background-color:#9B59B6;
    margin: -19px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Browser have default padding on a page, you can disable that with `html, body { padding: 0 }` instead of the `margin: -17px`

Answer (score 1):

```
body{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

#background
{ 
    position:absolute; 
    height:100%; 
    width:100%;
    background-color:#9B59B6;
    margin: 0px 0 0 0;

}
```

Comment: Can you edit your proposed answer to expand on what this does and how it addresses the OP?